# "create-react-app" debugging not working in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, debugging, intellij-idea, webstorm, create-react-app

I recently updated my web app project to use "create-react-app" rather than a lashed-together Webpack and Babel configuration.

Previously the debugging in WebStorm was working perfectly with the JetBrains Chrome extension.

Now however, when I set a breakpoint in JavaScript (.jsx) files in the project it doesn't stop at the breakpoints. but if I put a breakpoint on a in-line script in the index.html file it works and if I enable " break on exception" it works in that case.

I'm really confused. Any help or suggestions would be fantastic (it's probably something simple).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the solution:

update webstorm to "WebStorm-EAP-171.3019.10" :
https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/WebStorm+EAP

and then follow the configuration here : 
https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2017/01/debugging-react-apps/